# Pedaling overhead with front vs rear hub motor

Tags: electric-bike

When pedaling with the motor not working, would a rear geared hub motor give more resistance when accelerating or a front geared hub motor?

Given that the the torque from pedaling is applied to the rear wheel, making the rear wheel heavier might offer more acceleration resistance than adding the same weight to the front wheel (my reasoning).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming both wheels are the same radius (which they usually are) and that you're not skidding (which you usually aren't), both wheels rotate at the same speed and accelerate at the same rate. So, purely in the terms you mention in the question, it makes no difference.

If there is any difference, it will come from differing designs of front and rear hub motors.